# I can't translate position, name and price on sort by list

Tags: magento-1, price, sort, position, name

I have problem with translations.
I've tried translate it in translate.csv and mage_catalog.csv and it doesn't work.

[image: position]

position == Pozycja

[image: name]

name == Nazwa

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried a "Mage_Catalog::position","Pozycja" in translate.csv?

EDIT: Check your frontend/yourthemename/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml and try to find the block that is doing the translation.
Maybe there is in the select box just something like 
`<?php echo ($_order) ?>` instead of `<?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>`

Comment: Yes, still doesn't work..

Comment: Maybe another translation.csv is after your translate.csv? With some kind of empty string or wrong translation? Tried it in an test environmet and added as said in the answer and it changed after refresh. Was using another word, but ok.

Done edit on answer.

Comment: in toolbar.phtml i have  <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>

Comment: <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>               
              <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>">
                    <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
                </a>
              </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: Then i don't know, sorry. It seems correct to me. Last thing i would suggest: Clear all kind of caches and remove var/cache/* ... I had scenarios where i had to reset all kind of caches + restart apache and/or php-fpm due to caching. But this is something like 1 of 100 times.

Comment: After clearing cache files it's still the same

Comment: in url is ....asc&order=name   instead of asc&order=Nazwa

Comment: Well, in the URL there is still the order key, which is e.g. name or position. The problem is the translation itself in the frontend, and this has nothing to do with the URL GET parametes.
Sure you're in the correct phtml? Or maybe like said before, another translation file? Or there is something other like the echo $this->__($_order) on the selected item?